# Integrating $\int{\frac{2\,dx}{x^4+2x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am stuck on this problem.

I proceeded to cheat and used a calculator, but got stuck again on this step:

[image]
How do we get from the first integration to the second ?

Comment: Do you know how to perform partial fraction decomposition by hand?

Comment: Yes I've been applying it for the past few exercises but this example has me thinking my process is flawed @Ed_4434

Comment: Just as a quick pointer; you've asked about integrating $\int\frac{2}{x^4 + 2x^2} dx$ but in the body of the question you've given the integral as $\int\frac{1}{x^2(x^2 + 2)} dx$. Was this intended?

Comment: Partial Fraction Decomposition: $\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+2}$

Comment: @Ed_4434 Yes it was, just figured I'd do a few trivial manipulations

Comment: Okay that's fine. In that case, follow what @imranfat has pointed out and you should be fine! What problems are you encountering?

Comment: The partial fractions machinery is the general process, but one could note by inspection that $\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+2}=\frac{2}{x^2(x^2+2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put $$\dfrac{1}{x^4+2x^2}=\dfrac{1}{x^2(x^2+2)}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x^2}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+2}$$ and then make the sum of fractions and compare to find $A,B,C,D$.

I haven´t checked, but given the answer probably you will get $A=0,B=\frac{1}{2},C=0,D=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: An observation: notice that the denominator is $p(x^2)$, where $p(t)$ is a suitable polynomial of degree $2$. So you can avoid $\frac Ax$ and $\frac{Cx}{x^2+2}$, in the decomposition.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I didn't know that, but once you said it it make a lot of sense.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli could you please elaborate which denominator $p(x^2)$ you're speaking of ?

Comment: @user27454 To be fair, you'd be also using the fact that the same thing can be said of the numerator. Basically, the idea is that you know that there exist constants $B$ and $D$ such that $\dfrac{B}{t}+\dfrac{D}{t+2}=\dfrac{1}{t(t+2)}$. These work when you put $t=x^2$ as well.

Comment: @EricJohnson $p(t)=t(t+2)$, $p(x^2)=x^2(x^2+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to solve if you substitute $x=\sqrt 2 \tan y$